# What's the best way to track around 20M analytics events per day?

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, redis, matomo

We're using Apache + Piwik + Redis + MySQL for tracking data from customer websites, and we're now handling about 2M requests per day.
We need to scale up to 20M requests per day, so leading to 600M requests per month, at least. We're not confident that the current architecture could handle this high volume, in particular we're concerned about the MySQL server, which is the real bottleneck of our current architecture.
We're now implementing a custom analytics server w/ [Minuteman](https://github.com/elcuervo/minuteman).

Are there other valuable options?
Has anyone handled 600M+ requests/month with Piwik?

Thanks!

Comment: It seem you are looking for self-hosted open-source solutions only ? Maybe you could make that clearer in your question.